# Dawn simulation - does color change affect waking up?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, light

just curious. Are there any works or research results related to the influence of light color used for [dawn simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_simulation)? I mean those wake-up lights which try to simulate dawn to make waking up better for you.

The cheap ones only use one color - those "warm white" LEDs - and only change brightness. However the more expensive ones also change color like the sun during sunrise.

I am just curious how much important could be the color change. :-)

thanks